# How to maintain state of switch button inside tableviewcell with searchbar in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Description : i have a content in tableview along with switch button .

Problem : after using the searchbar for serching items in tableview state of switch button is lost - switch button which was set on for row 0 and row 1 has lost .

Comment: Please add your code. How you are doing it?

Comment: @hi Daljeet - i am not able to perform .. what i have done yet .. bind the tableview with JSON api response . tableview searching is working fine . but state of the button which was on or off is lost during tableview.reloaddata

Comment: For that you have to store the state of that button with your data and read that data, handle the button UI accordingly. Hope you understand.

Comment: Great Let me know if you need any help If you can add code I can modify and help you.

Comment: @VinodSaini have you tried my answer provide below?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to store button state with your data.

And Read the data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` Handle UI

**Example:**

```
 if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1{
    // Handle Button UI here
    let value = buttonArrayData[indexPath.row]
      if(value){
         //button selected
         //update buttonArrayData data accordingly.
      }
      else{
       //button unselected
       //update buttonArrayData data accordingly.   
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem associated with `UISearchBar` but seems because of TableView reload.

To save the state of `UISwitch` in the case of table reload, you need have a custom `UITableViewCell` class and `UISwitch` outlet inside it.

> Then to save a `UISwitch` state for further use

You can store only the selected cell index as state in `UserDefault` and check the same against the current index in `cellForRowAt` tableView method. If it is found then your last state is `ON` otherwise default one is `OFF`.

This code snippet will work as you expect:

> Custom `UITableViewCell` class

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var switchObj: UISwitch!
  @IBOutlet weak var textValue: UILabel!

  @IBAction func toggleState(_ sender: Any) {
    var loadValues: [Int: Bool]!
    if let values = Memory.getStatesFromMemory() {
      loadValues = values
    } else {
      loadValues = [Int: Bool]()
    }
    loadValues[switchObj.tag] = switchObj.isOn
    Memory.saveSwitchStatesToMemory(savedStates: loadValues)
  }
}
```

> `UIViewController` class

```
class CustomTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  var savedStates: [Int: Bool]!

  override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let values = Memory.getStatesFromMemory() {
      savedStates = values
    } else {
      savedStates = [Int: Bool]()
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as? CustomCell
    cell?.switchObj.isOn = savedStates[indexPath.row] == nil ? false : savedStates[indexPath.row]!
    cell?.switchObj.tag = indexPath.row
    cell?.textValue.text = "Switch stored state >>"
    return cell!
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 80
  }
}
```

> Custom class to use for save/retrieve values from memory

```
class Memory {

  static func getStatesFromMemory() -> [Int: Bool]? {
    if let switchValues = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SwitchStates") as? Data {
      let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: switchValues) as! [Int: Bool]
      return decodedTeams
    }
    return nil
  }

  static func saveSwitchStatesToMemory(savedStates: [Int: Bool]) {
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: savedStates)
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "SwitchStates")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
  }
}
```